# How to configure a cluster that is write optimized and with minimum resources consumption footprint

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization

I am very new to ES, and would like to start indexing several logs files that are printed across components in the same machine, and across several machines on top of eventviewer entries on each machine.

At times with extended traces enabled there could be a high amount of writes, and I would like to keep indexing as fast and lightweight as possible.

Searching the logs would be a very rare operation done by a single user 
at a time, and as long as it takes up to ~5 seconds I am ok with that.

My initial thoughts, if it is possible, is to only allocate a single Index and Shard per each (machine, component, day) tupple which would reside on the local machine itself.
This hopefully would reduce all nodes coordination to minimum, and at query time all results would just need to be aggregated from all the nodes.

My question is will this be possible (I plan to use logstash in order to push data to ES) or is this even a good approach for my needs?

Thanks,
Leon

Answer (score 0):

You cant optimize before starting to index your data or at least have a realistic idea of your data volume.

But for this part :

> My initial thoughts, if it is possible, is to only allocate a single
>   Index and Shard per each (machine, component, day) tupple which would
>   reside on the local machine itself

You will create too many indices. There is no magic number with ES, but a Lucene shard is usually correctly sized when its size is between 4 and 20Go of data ( if you dont use parent/child or nested structure). Below 4Go you consume CPU cycle for nothing and you add a useless burden on your cluster.

So try to estimate how many logs you will produce per day / per component. And maybe think about monthly indices or daily multicomponent.

Comment: Thanks for the info Pierre, I can definitely move to monthly indices.

Comment: Have you any input about the expected throughput ? You know elastic is out the box pretty fast. There is a good chance that an out of the box configuration will be sufficient

Comment: I would say that in the worst case I don't expect more than 3k docs per second on each machine.